# How to properly create a textNode and append to a specific place?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I am trying to simply append a textNode to `<h1>` and then append it to the body into a `<div id="prob3">`, but I get this error `TypeError: bdy.appendChild is not a function` on `bdy.appendChild(header);`. What is wrong with this piece of code?

**JavaScript Code (embedded in the head tag):**

```
function init()
{
   var bdy = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
   var header = document.createElement("h1");
   var txt = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");
   header.appendChild(txt);
   bdy.appendChild(header);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="init();">
     <div id="prob3">
         <!--Created TextNode goes Here-->
     </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use:

```
document.body.appendChild(header);
```

---

Your code wasn't working because:

```
var bdy = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

retrieves a list of elements, not a single element.  You could have used:

```
var bdy = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

to get the first element from the list, but there's no point in doing it this way since `document.body` is already predefined for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you also do things like, `document.head`, `document.title`? I'm playing around with extracting things outside of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight - `document.title` is widely supported.  `document.head` is only supported in IE starting with IE9.  You can use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head) as a good reference for things like this as it will tell you what is supported in which browser versions.

Comment: okay, I tried to dynamically create title with JS, similar to the body, but doesn't work.

       `var titler = document.createElement("title");
   
var titleTxt = document.createTextNode("Practical 340 Review JS");
   
titler.appendChild(titleTxt);
   
document.title.appendChild(titler);`

Comment: The `document.title.innerHTML = "Practical 340 Review JS";` doesn't work either.

Comment: `document.title = "don’t over-complicate shit"` … you’ve been told about MDN already, so go make some use of it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight - yep, CBroe has it right here.  It's just `document.title = "Practical 340 Review JS";`.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` gets you a NodeList, and you can’t append to that – you would have to get out the first element of that list first, `getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild`.

But every browser understands `document.body` as a shortcut to the body element.

Answer (score 2):

In this method call:

```
 var bdy = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

Notice "elements" is plural. Which means in all likelihood it returns an array-like structure (in this case a NodeList). Arrays naturally don't have a `.appendChild` method. You can tell this by inspecting `bdy` in a debugger, or more bluntly by `console.log`-ing it.